# select ddl item based on the url

Tags: c#, user-controls, umbraco

On my contact page (contact.aspx)I have a booking form that contains a drop down list control which is dynamically populated with the names of the available drivers to choose from. What I would like to do is on each drivers individual page e.g driver1.aspx provide a 'book this driver' link which when the user selects it they are taken to the contact page and the drop down list is populated with the drivers name of the page they have just come from.

so for example if i am a user viewing Pauls driver page and i select book this driver i am taken to the contact us page and the ddl list has pre selected paul as the prefered driver

Can this be achieved? If so has and one got any links or advice on how to do it?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: are you familiar with the `URI` for example you could do something like the following then inspect the variable / object to see what properties you are trying to access.. `var url = new Uri('your url');` can you post what your Url looks like.. then seeing that it should be a piece of cake from there in regards to setting the DDL SelectedIndex based on the value you assign to the `url` variable..

Comment: Hey Method man, thanks for your response, I been busy working on this and have achieved it using the following

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your response, I been busy working on this and have achieved it using the following (not sure its the best approach but its doing what i need)

if you can suggest anything better then please let me know :)

```
//gets the full url of the referal page e.g http://mysite.co.uk/our-drivers/joe-bloggs.aspx
string refererPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

//splits the referer url to get the latter part containing the name  e.g joe-bloggs.aspx
string url = refererPage.Split('/').Last();
//splits the url to get the first part of the url e.g joe-bloggs
string url2 = url.Split('.').First();

        // Take the value of url2 replace the hyphen with a space e.g Joe Bloggs then loop through 
        // the items in the DDL and if there is an item that matches make it the selected item
        foreach (ListItem item in ddlPreferedDriver.Items)
        {
            if (url2.ToLower().Replace("-", " ").Contains(item.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

cheers Paul